# Unable To Convert Numpy Array to Image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a simple image using Numpy and PIL. However, I seem to be getting this bizarre image instead of what I expected.
My code (Cell wise in a jupyter notebook)

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

arr = np.zeros([100,100,3])
arr[:,:] = [255,128,0]
img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGB')
img
```

The resultant image is this: [image]

I expected an image which would've been completely orange.

Comment: Set the `dtype=np.uint8` when you create it.

Comment: Also, `arr[:,:,:]`